# L'antériorisation vocalique dans l'accent de Newcastle : phénomène similaire en langue française ?

Tags: phonétique, linguistique, comparaison-de-langues, genre-biologique

Dans un [autre](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12578) contexte on m'a [présenté](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/specifics-about-the-impact-of-natural-gender-on-pronunciation#comment41534_12578) l'*idée* de l'antériorisation (vocalique) de la voyelle en langue anglaise dans l'accent de Newcastle. D'un côté on [explique](https://books.google.com/books?id=zhd3EDtMihMC&lpg=PA30&ots=FtWHXoKpm4&dq=ant%C3%A9riorisation%20vocalique&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q=ant%C3%A9riorisation%20vocalique&f=false) que l' « antériorisation des voyelles d'arrière permet d'éviter la convergence des phonèmes », et on dit d'autre part que « l'antériorisation des voyelles postérieures et moyennes créé un risque de convergence entre les voyelles antériorisées et les voyelles d'avant » avec des mots comme : *serve, save ; turn, ten ; bird, bade, bed* (*La fonction expressive*, Volume 1, Catherine Paulin, aux Presses Univ. Franche-Comté, 2007).

---

- Y a-t-il un phénomène moderne comparable à l'antériorisation de
  la voyelle ou qui emporte un risque similaire de convergence dans la prononciation, en langue française ? Vers quoi tend la prononciation moderne du français ?
- Les locutrices les plus jeunes de la francophonie font-elles
  aujourd'hui des choix de styles phonétiques qui leur sont communs et
  qui sont en rupture avec les choix antérieurs, avec la prononciation des autres locuteurs, et comparables aux innovations de Newcastle ; quels sont-ils sommairement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je crois que ce phénomène (de déplacement en chaîne des voyelles) est beaucoup plus commun en anglais qu'en français. De fait je n'en connais pas vraiment d'exemple en français actuel (quoiqu'on en trouve probablement au moment de la transition du latin au roman). Cela serait dû selon moi à deux différences structurelles entre les deux langues:

- Les voyelles anglaises sont non seulement plus "vagues" (c'est-à-dire que leur prononciation tend à être plus variable dès le départ, impression totalement subjective de ma part, je l'avoue !) mais aussi *plus nombreuses* que les voyelles françaises, et donc plus à risque, dès lors que la prononciation change, d'empiéter sur une autre voyelle. C'est d'autant plus vrai si l'on ne compare que les voyelles orales des deux langues (éliminant du décompte les deux à quatre, selon l'accent, voyelles nasales, qui ne peuvent empiéter sur les orales en français).
- La tendance naturelle du français, voire de l'ensemble des langues latines, tend non à "déplacer" les voyelles dans l'espace vocalique pour les garder distinctes, mais plutôt à accepter assez aisément leur combinaison, d'où une différence qui peut aller *du simple au double* entre les voyelles de différents dialectes : 17 en français québécois contre seulement 9 dans les dialectes du sud de la France où les nasales sont allophoniques et prononcées "à l'anglaise" (et d'ailleurs sont souvent transcrites -*ang*, -*aing* etc.).

Comment: Merci, c'est une question d'introduction parce qu'il me manque bcp. de notions pour comprendre ce sujet. Mais j'aimerais savoir aussi un peu en quoi la voix/prononciation des femmes change cette donne aujourd'hui. Pourquoi leur prononciation est un vecteur d'innovation linguistique ? C'est quoi le _conservatisme_ dans la prononciation ? S'il y avait confusion comme suite à la convergence de _serve_ et _save_, quelle stratégie la langue va-t-elle déployer pour clarifier ça ? À partir de votre propos un néophyte doit-il retenir que la tendance est diamétralement opposée entre En/Fr ?

Comment: Ou ne peut-on pas comparer car on parle de tendance naturelle du français vs. un phénomène qui n'est pas de tendance générale (ou générale pour un locuteur d'un genre particulier) ? Dans le truc de Newcastle, j'ai lu que l'antériorisation vocalique n'est pas un phénomène récent en anglais, mais que sa fréquence l'est chez ces locutrices de Newcastle et plus largement. La sociologie est-elle un vecteur majeur des transformations linguistiques, généralement ? Quelle transformation sociologique affecte le fait français aujourd'hui ? Ces questions illustrent ce que j'ai ds. le coco. Merci encore.

Comment: Je ne sais pas d'où sort le sujet des femmes ou du conservatisme par rapport à la question d'origine. Je sais qu'il y a [un phénomène relativement bien établi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_paradox) comme quoi les femmes (plus exactement les femmes d'avant garde de la classe moyenne supérieur) sont souvent à la pointe de ces changements et les répandent autour d'elles (en plus de les transmettre à leurs enfants). Il me semble clair que c'est ce qui se passe dans l'étude de Newcastle, mais l'origine du changement lui même n'est pas liée au sexe des locutrices.

Comment: Et par "pas liée au sexe des locutrices", je veux dire qu'un changement linguistique n'a virtuellement jamais de base biologique. Toutefois, mes connaissances de l'état du français globalement ou des tendances de ce genre à travers différents groupes de langues ne sont pas suffisamment avancées pour que j'ose élaborer plus sur la question (la sociolinguistique, en dehors des débats sur la correctude de l'usage, est généralement au-delà de mes compétences). Je te conseillerais de lire plus en détails sur le phénomène du *gender paradox* et de voir ce que tu peux en tirer.

Comment: Merci pour ces précisions ! C'est que je suis influencé par la question que j'avais posée sur Linguistics où l'on parle des différences biologiques au niveau de la prononciation. Mais j'ai compris de Newcastle que ce dont on y traitait était particulier aux femme plus jeunes ; seulement l'âge serait le facteur significatif et non pas le sexe dans ce cas ? Comme j'ai dit c'est une question d'intro et je dois en lire davantage sur le sujet, à l'évidence !

Comment: Non, le sexe est éminemment pertinent dans le cas du *gender paradox* (je n'ai personnellement jamais entendu parler de théorie liant les changements phonétiques à des différences sexuelles d'ordre anatomique) puisque ce sont les femmes qui transmettent généralement des particularités linguistiques à leurs enfants. Si on touche à une tranche d'âge plus jeune, au niveaux des adolescentes, on tombe plutôt dans une espèce de "cassure générationnelle" (c'est-à-dire des jeunes qui s'efforcent spécifiquement de parler différemment de leurs parents), phénomène pas exactement  lié au sexe du locuteur.